# Why won't bookmarks work on my PDFLatex Document?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

Would someone please help me to figure out why bookmarks won't work in my PDF Latex document?  I'm using a Macbook.

Thanks,

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper, oneside, table]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{natbib, booktabs, tabularx, array, multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{caption,pdfpages} 
\usepackage[driver=pdftex]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{float, threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true, pdfauthor={author}, pdftitle={title}, hidelinks, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarks=true, bookmarksopenlevel=3, pdfsubject={subject}, pdfcreator=company name]{hyperref}

\hfuzz=15.5pt
\hyphenpenalty=1000


\begin{document}

\LARGE{This is a Very Interesting Document \\about Yukon Black Bears.}
\newpage

\tableofcontents



\newpage
\section{Introduction}Have you ever heard about Yukon black bears?

\newpage
\section{Body}They wake from hibernation at the sound of water flowing.

\newpage        
\section{Conclusions}Be careful when enjoying spring hikes.

\newpage
\section{Recommendations}Make sure you always bring bear spray.
\subsection{Bear Spray}When deploying bear spray, ensure the bear is quite near, or that it is downwind.
\subsection{Risks}Otherwise, you may end up spraying yourself, which is unpleasant.

\newpage
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage
\newpage

\begin{appendices}
    \newpage
    \section{Some Really Interesting Appendix}  \label{appendix-a}
    \newpage
\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Have you compiled it two times? Not sure if that is necessary.

Comment: Yes.  I have compiled it about 35 times or more.  I can't figure it out.  It's driving me crazy.

Comment: You've said that bookmarks won't work and aren't displayed.  Could you be more specific?  Are you talking about the hyperlinks in the pdf that hyperref creates?   Are they not boxed?  Or does clicking them not do anything?  Or are you talking about the left hand side of the Preview app?  What do you see there?  Have you tried going through all of the options under "View"?  I don't see anything for "View" -> "Bookmarks", but I see everything I expect under "View" -> "Table of Contents".

Comment: Yes! You are completely correct.  I can't believe I didn't see that before.  What a silly question that was.  Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Mac app Preview, the pdf's bookmarks can be found by going to "View" and then "Table of Contents".  (I think "View" -> "Bookmarks" is for bookmarks that you've created with "Tools" -> "Add Bookmark".)